# Visual c++ programatically get file version number within the file itself

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know I can call `GetFileVersionInfo()` windows API to retrieve file version information.

Is there an easier way to determine the version information, from within the program itself?

For example, suppose I am writing codes for `Foo.dll`, and inside `Foo.dll`, I want to support a version function, say  `GetFooVersion()`, which reports the version number of `Foo.dll`.

If I have to use `GetFileVersionInfo()`, then I need to search which `Foo.dll` in the path that is been linked (dynamically), and apply `GetFileVersionInfo()`.  It's tedious and error-prone.

The target visual studio version is VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

There is no GetFileVersionInfoByHandle nor GetFileVersionInfoFromModule unfortunately.

You can use `FindResource` etc. on your own module but you then have to parse the version info yourself because `GetFileVersionInfo` does not always retrieve the raw resource data (it can translate to/from Unicode etc.).

Another option is to put version #defines in a .h file that your function and your resource.rc can use so you only have to update a single file when the version changes.